# dynamic xml, changing text

Tags: android, xml

Hello I want to do this: I am pulling data from a server and I need when for example pull out the number 0 the textview to ber red color, on any other case to be green color. I do not know if there is a way of placing something like an if statement in the xml file or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to to first instantiate your text view like

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idOfTextViewInXML);
```

Now you can perform change this text view as you please . For example

```
if(var==0)
    tv.setText("VALUE IS ZERO");
else
    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

This is the way you need to change the features of views dynamically . You can't really change the XML itself dynamically .

All this must be performed in the Java class .

Comment: I want the textcolour to change, not the background. the text will be the same but depending on the value, textcolur must change. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Once u have data from sever in form of xml , parser the xml and process it (to check for your condition ).

Answer (score 0):

When you parse your xml in your code, just add a if statement.

```
if(number == 0){


 else{
 //do something
  }
```