# How can I change the font color of the textview in the listview from xml file item? android

Tags: java, android

Depending on the value:

Example

Pay:+200

Pay:-100

If the value of pay is higher the color of 200 is green. 
If the value of pay is lower the color of 100 is red.

It changes color every seconds because I have xml file link from the browser 
and update the xml file every seconds. 
I like the color together as the link in my xml file refresh it in seconds and change the color depends if higher or lower.

Comment: That you have to do it programmatically.

Comment: check this [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759152/dynamic-xml-changing-text)

Comment: it can achieve using programmatically while binding the adpter with listview

Comment: I use list Adapter and simple adapter.:) thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Here if you mean the xml file to be of xml parsing, try the following one

while your placing the text in listview from xml file, get the color from the xml file and parse it as follows

String txt = "`<font color=#408cc4>`"+"here text you need to print"+"";
            viewHolder.activity_hold_heading.setText(Html.fromHtml(txt));

here `color = the color you need`

Answer (score 1):

Try to getGroupView method of base adapter class.According to value you get try set differnt colors as follows.

Before the method :

1) you have to get value(text need to be highlighted) from String and parse it to int and compare.

2) you have to get start and end index of your value(text need to be highlighted) from the String.

```
            @Override
              public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(valuestring);
                if(yourvalue>200){
                     WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("##00FF40")),start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);    
                }else if (yourvalue<100){
                    WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#DF0101")),start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);          
                }
                yourtextview.setText(WordtoSpan);
           }
```

Comment: I follow your instructions, actually I put it in code in downpart of my xml parse with timer. the override has error so I didn't put override then the valuestring has error I didn't know what can I put in valuestring the error says alternate of this getstring. then I put pay boys as yourvalue >  + color green same as else pay girls as yourvalue < - color red. has  error

Answer (score 1):

to achieve this you need to bind data with Simpleadpter and using ViewBinder you can get the String values and Update the Color As per your Requirement  and to update the data make  adpter Notifydatasetchange

```
adapater1 = new SimpleAdapter(Byshedulelist.this, shedulelist, R.layout.rowshedule,
                    new String[] { "im","Countryname", "Titel"},
                    new int[] { R.id.rowshedulecountryimg,R.id.shedulerowCountrynametxt, R.id.shedulerowtitle,});                   


            adapater1.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder1());           
            itemlist.setAdapter(adapater1);



 class MyViewBinder1 implements ViewBinder 
 {      @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object Status,String textRepresentation)
            {       
                  String complet="Pay:+200 ";
                  String notcomlet="Pay:-100";

                  String getdata= textRepresentation;


                    if((view instanceof TextView) & (Status instanceof String) )
                    { 
                            TextView iv= (TextView) view;     
                            if(complet.equals(Status))
                                {
                                r1=true;
                                r2=false;
                            iv.setText(textRepresentation);       
                            iv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));                
                            return true;
                           }   
                            else if(notcomlet.equals(Status))
                            {
                                r2=true;
                                r1=false;
                                iv.setText(textRepresentation);       
                                iv.setTextColor(Color.RED); 
                                return true;
                            }

                            if(r1 && (getdata.startsWith("Pay:   ")))
                           {                            

                            iv.setText(textRepresentation);      

                            iv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));                           
                            return true;
                           }
                        else if (r2 && (getdata.startsWith("Pay:   ")))
                        {
                            //TextView iv= (TextView) view;
                            iv.setText(textRepresentation);       
                            iv.setTextColor(Color.RED);                              
                            return true;
                        }                           
                    }        
                  return false;
            }           
}
```

Comment: where I can I put your code (example) to me in my code to my application? I'm using dom parser that parse my xml file in the browser that update in 5 seconds and I'm using timer on that also I'm using simpleadapter and listadapter thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String txt = "<font color=Red>"+"-100"+"";
String txt = "<font color=Green>"+"200"+""; 
viewHolder.activity_hold_heading.setText(Html.fromHtml(txt));
```